# Configure node-sass in PhpStorm

Tags: npm, phpstorm, webstorm, node-sass

I have the following directory structure:

```
-dir
 --css
 --scss
   --main.scss
```

Now after compiling a file I have:

```
-dir
 --css
 --scss
   --main.scss
    -main.css
```

My File Watcher settings for **node-sass**:

[image]

How can I compile all `.scss` files into `css` folder?

```
-dir
 --css
   --main.css
 --scss
    main.scss
```

Comment: `node-sass --help` tells that you need to use `--output` (or `-o`) parameter and specify the output folder. In your case something like `..\css` as the path *should* do the job (assuming that *working directory* will be where the source `.scss` file is located; otherwise click on `Insert Macro` button and insert the most suitable one)

Answer (score 1):

It can be smth like:

**Arguments:** `$FileName$ --source-map=true -o $ProjectFileDir$/css`

**Output paths to refresh:** `$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

**Working directory:** `$FileDir$`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your argument creates a folder at the very root, I just needed to go to the parent folder, I managed to do it like this
I change Arguments: `$FileName$ $FileParentDir$\css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you need to navigate to the parent folder

Arguments: `$FileName$ $FileParentDir$\css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Output: `$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`